# Different combinations of objects with restrictions

Tags: combinatorics

first of all please excuse the title, hopefully the question will make it more clear.

Suppose that there are 17 students in a class. For assignment 1, the students are to partition themselves into 4 non-empty groups. For assignment 2, the students are again to partition themselves into 4 non-empty groups, but with the added restriction that no two students who worked together on the first assignment can work together on the second assignment. Is it possible to satisfy this restriction?

This is the approach I took:
Let A, B, C, D denote the sets of students for the first assignment, and A', B', C', D' denote the sets of students for the second assignment.
If no two students can work on both assignment 1 and 2 together, then we can draw the following:
$$
\left | A \cap A'  \right | \in \{0, 1\}\\
\left | A \cap B'  \right | \in \{0, 1\}\\
\left | A \cap C'  \right | \in \{0, 1\}\\
\left | A \cap D'  \right | \in \{0, 1\}\\
\left | B \cap A'  \right | \in \{0, 1\}\\
\left | B \cap B'  \right | \in \{0, 1\}\\
\left | B \cap C'  \right | \in \{0, 1\}\\
\left | B \cap D'  \right | \in \{0, 1\}\\
\left | C \cap A'  \right | \in \{0, 1\}\\
\left | C \cap B'  \right | \in \{0, 1\}\\
\left | C \cap C'  \right | \in \{0, 1\}\\
\left | C \cap D'  \right | \in \{0, 1\}\\
\left | D \cap A'  \right | \in \{0, 1\}\\
\left | D \cap B'  \right | \in \{0, 1\}\\
\left | D \cap C'  \right | \in \{0, 1\}\\
\left | D \cap D'  \right | \in \{0, 1\}\\
$$

We also know that all these unions cover all the sets of students, e.g.
$$
A' = (A \cap A') \cup (B \cap A') \cup (C \cap A') \cup (D \cap A')\\
$$
We can make similar statements for B', C' and D'.

"Summing" all of the sizes of the intersections gives us a combined size of A', B', C' and D' of somewhere between 0 and 16, which is a contradiction as we know we have 17 students, therefore we cannot meet the constraint.

Is this correct reasoning? I know it isn't massively rigorous (perhaps someone could help me with that if this is a valid argument).
In what other ways can this type of problem be approached.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds pretty good to me, except that all the unions in your first $16$ equations should be intersections.

Comment: Eugh what a silly typing error, will edit that now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your reasoning looks fine.

You could use a bit of subscripting to help you, perhaps. Call the first task groups $A_1, A_2, A_3, A_4$ and the second task groups $B_1,B_2,B_3,B_4$. Then define the groups $C_{ij}$ with $i,j=1..4$ as $C_{ij}=A_i\cap B_j$.

Allocating the students to their two groups is then choosing which of the $C_{ij}$ groups each goes into. The condition is that all $C_{ij}$ have maximum size of 1, but there are 16 groups and 17 students, so we fail by the pigeonhole principle.